# How can I properly print the function call?

Tags: c

It comes out as 0.0. I want it to come out as a number other than 0, unless the input number was 0 of course. I tried a few things. Here is the current code.

```
#include <stdio.h>                                     /* Necessary header */
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    double Initial;
    double Post;

    printf("Enter a number with a decimal: ");
    scanf("%lf", &Initial);
    printf("Enter another number using the same format: ");
    scanf("%lf", &Post);

    ComputeMinimum(Initial, Post);
    ComputeMaximum(Initial, Post);

    printf("Of %1.1lf and %1.1lf ", Initial, Post);
    printf("the minimum is %1.1lf ", ComputeMinimum(Initial, Post));
    printf("and the maximum is %1.1lf.", ComputeMaximum(Initial, Post));

    return 0;
}

    double ComputeMaximum(double B, double A)
{
    return (A > B) ? A : B;
}

double ComputeMinimum(double a, double b)
{
    return (a < b) ? a : b;
}
```

I have already tried the following. ALso, I am supposed to make the return type for the functions double, not sure how though.

```
int main()
{
    double Initial;
    double Post;

    printf("Enter a number with a decimal: ");
    scanf("%lf", &Initial);
    printf("Enter another number using the same format: ");
    scanf("%lf", &Post);

    double minimum = ComputeMinimum(Initial, Post);
    double maximum = ComputeMaximum(Initial, Post);

    printf("Of %1.1lf and %1.1lf ", Initial, Post);
    printf("the minimum is %1.1lf ", minimum);
    printf("and the maximum is %1.1lf.", maximum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works for me on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/EMhNhR) after taking the functions to the head of the file - of course. (Don't forget to "upload with new input" when checking it there)

Comment: If you liked the answers, you can always vote them up ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, it works perfectly fine for me.

You should add function declarations before main, so it gets:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                     /* Necessary header */
#include <stdlib.h>

double ComputeMinimum(double a, double b);
double ComputeMaximum(double a, double b);

int main()
{
....
```

As for your next question, the return type of these functions IS `double`, so you don't have to change anything. The problem was that without the function prototypes a compiler does not know it will be `double`, so it assumes `int`.

Please enable compiler warnings, they are really helpful and you should always read them carefully.

Comment: Yes, it was the header... I have warnings, they just are too cryptic to understand.

Comment: Are you compiling on windows or on linux? If on linux, try and find "clang" and compile with "cland yourfile.c" - it gives you almost graphical output saying "the error is here" ;-) Anyway, try to read into these compiler messages, they will save you a lot of trouble!

Answer (score 0):

For me also it worked i.e. the above program in which you are catching the output in maximum and minimum as double. I think above mention of declaring the prototype is also correect or you can directly put the definition of the both the function above the main program, then in that case you don't even need prototype since it will work as prototype for the compiler as well